# Empty txt folder is created instead of txt file

Tags: android, file

An empty txt folder is created when I am trying to create a txt file with data from usb.

Another app with similar implementation work sometimes and cannot work sometime.

The coding attached below is just part of my coding.

May i know what is the problem ? I have refer several websites and forums on how to write to the file. I believe the approach i am using is the most general one. but somehow it is not working (or to be more precise. It works for one or two times and then no longer create any file).

```
private String filename = ".txt";
File myExternalFile;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(isExternalStorageAvailable() || !isExternalStorageReadOnly()){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        filename = "gas_sensor_"+currentDateandTime + filename;
        myExternalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), filename);
        if (!myExternalFile.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(logTag, "Directory not created");
        }else{
            Log.e(logTag, "Directory created");
        }
    }
}

private void tvAppend(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
    final TextView ftv = tv;
    final CharSequence ftext = text;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ftv.append(ftext);
            ftv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        }
    });

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile,true);
        fos.write(ftext.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You need to first make folder and then write file in particular folder

Comment: The folder i am using is Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS). please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: `mkdirs` will create a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You pass direct folder name instead file

```
try{
        File file = new File(myExternalFile, "your_file_name.txt")
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        fos.write(ftext.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake!
Too eager to complete the feature in a short time until such small silly mistake occured.